# Error in Printing all Primes Less than N (Java)

Tags: java, numbers

I'm trying to crate a program that prints all prime numbers less than or equal to an inputted number and the number of primes found. For instance, an input of 5 would print 2, 3, and 5. I made this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sample {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number:");
        int number=0;
        number=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        int counter=0;
        boolean isPrime=true;
        if (number<=1){
            System.out.println("O prime numbers found.");
        } else {
            for (int i=2; i<=number;i++){
                for (int j=2; j<i;j++){
                    if (i%j==0){
                        isPrime=false;
                        break;
                    } 
                }
            }
            if (isPrime(i)){
                System.out.println(i);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter+ " prime numbers found.");
    }
}
```

But it returns two errors that are as follows:

```
 error: cannot find symbol
        if (isPrime(i)){
                    ^
 symbol:   variable i
 location: class Sample
 error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println(i);
                       ^
 symbol:   variable i
 location: class Sample
```

Does anyone know why this won't work? Thank you.

Comment: is `isPrime(x)` even a method???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this block:

```
        for (int i=2; i<=number;i++){
            for (int j=2; j<i;j++){
                if (i%j==0){
                    isPrime=false;
                    break;
                } 
            }
        }
        if (isPrime(i)){
            System.out.println(i);
            counter++;
        }
```

with this:

```
        for (int i=2; i<=number;i++){
            for (int j=2; j<i;j++){
                if (i%j==0){
                    isPrime=false;
                    break;
                } 
            }
            if (isPrime){
                System.out.println(i);
                counter++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Though it points out a major issue in OPs code, this does not solve the primary error thrown in the `System.out.println(i)` statement.

Comment: Lol... In the edit you forgot to change the function to the boolean!

Comment: Indeed. In my defence, it's Friday.

Answer (score 1):

The statement block

```
if (isPrime(i)){
    System.out.println(i);
        counter++;
}
```

is outside the for loop that uses i.

---

**Edit:** From the code, it looks like you've pasted incomplete code or made some errors. For example, where is the isPrime() function defined? And is it really required? Ask these questions and revisit the code!

Comment: Thank you! I'm still getting a "cannot find symbol" error on:
    if (isPrime(i)){
        ^
  symbol:   method isPrime(int)
  location: class Sample
1 error

Comment: I have given a hint in the answer. You are calling isPrime as a function. Is that what you are supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you want to do:

1. Move the declaration (or at least the initialization) of the isPrime variable inside the i loop,
2. Move the test with the print inside the i loop and correct the condition (isPrime is a variable, not a method),

   ```
   if (number<=1){
       System.out.println("O prime numbers found.");
   } else {
       for (int i=2; i<=number;i++){
           boolean isPrime=true;
           for (int j=2; j<i;j++){
               if (i%j==0){
                   isPrime=false;
                   break;
               } 
           }
           if (isPrime){
               System.out.println(i);
               counter++;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Or, with a method isPrime:

```
for (int i=2; i<=number;i++){
    if (isPrime(i)) {
        System.out.println(i);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

...

```
static boolean isPrime(int i) {
    for (int j=2; j<i;j++){
        if (i%j==0){
            return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You define `i` in the for loop which is closed before the `if` statement.